# How cookies are handled in Webbrowser Control?

Tags: cookies, webbrowser-control

Does cookies in WebBrowser control acts as normal as in any other browser like Firefox or Chrome? I have made a simple interface for webbrowser control in VB, now im unable to manage login/logout of certain sites.

Some time the logout works and some time dont. Do I need to add additional code for cookie handling for Web browser control or it will do everything itself.

Where do I can read more about WebBrowser control except MSDN.

I found this code:

```
 webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")
```

Answer (score 0):

[A cookie can be marked as "HttpOnly"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384321.aspx) (attributes are not case-sensitive), to indicate that the cookie is "**non-scriptable**" and should not be revealed to the client application, for security reasons.

Also your top level document may not have access to the authentication cookie [if it is on another domain](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/784102).